# Do I need to use the function form of 'use strict' in jasmine test files?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jshint, use-strict

I'm building unit tests in jasmine based on examples I've seen with AngularJS. The examples, such as [this unit test in the Angular PhoneCat tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/test/unit/filtersSpec.js), use the global form of `'use strict'`. However, JSHint complains that I should

> Use the function form of "use strict".

I know why `'use strict'` is important, and I think I understand why you should use the function form of `'use strict'` instead of the global form in your source files. However, in jasmine test files, is it OK to use the **global form** of `'use strict'`?

If so, can I suppress these JSHint warnings for my jasmine test files only?

Comment: As far as I know, 'use strict' is simply to encourage better coding practices.    For test cases I would just ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can ignore it, in JSHint, but as [vihan1086](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1620622/vihan1086) said, this will urge you to write better code, by throwing exceptions. See the following post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this misses the question a bit. I've updated my post to clarify what I'm asking.